# IBM Bluemix NoAppDetectedError when uploading application

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud

Anyone ever have any issues uploading their own app? I have my app file unzipped on my desktop and nothing seems to work. Also the file is 39 MB not 3 MB

```
C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\test>cf push test
Creating app test in org mweiner_org / space dev as xxx@gmail.com...
OK

Creating route test.mybluemix.net...
OK

Binding test.mybluemix.net to findmy...
OK

Uploading test...
Uploading app files from: C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\test
Uploading 3.9M, 2024 files
Done uploading
OK

Starting app findmy in org mweiner_org / space dev as xxx@gmail.com
    Staging failed: An application could not be detected by any available buildpack


FAILED
NoAppDetectedError

TIP: use 'cf logs findmy --recent' for more information
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Try specifying -m and giving a memory value like:

```
cf push appname -m 512M
```

2) I see you're taking the default buildpack, is that your intention?

3) Try using the following command to gather only staging errors:

```
cf logs appname --recent | grep '\[STG\]'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The app was coded in xpages but there is no .nsf file

Answer (score 1):

When you push an application to Bluemix without specifying a buildpack, all of the pre-installed buildpacks (`cf buildpacks`) will try to see if they are capable of running your application (buildpack detect script).  In your case, none of the buildpacks think they are capable.

What kind of application is in your "test" folder? You can force a buildpack to try to run your application by either specifying the buildpack name or [URL of a publicly hosted buildpack](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/).

`cf push <appname> -b <name or url of buildpack>`

Comment: `cf push <appname> -b xpages_buildpack` If that doesn't work, look at this xpages sample: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/xpages-web-starter/

Comment: Xcode is not a programming language. It is code editor, an IDE for macs. Is this an app for an iPhone?

Comment: Objective c with a rest api in the background

Comment: This type of application is not supported by Bluemix.

Comment: so you are saying Object C is not supported by Blue Mix?

Comment: Right - Objective C apps are generally meant to be run on iOS and OS X devices - not as a web application. You can use Bluemix mobile services as a backend for your mobile application, but the application itself will run on a device.